# <video /> tag in server side generated Next.JS page causes hydration failure

Tags: javascript, html, next.js

The index page of my Next.js app is rendered on the server side.

While developing the app, I have been getting the following error:

> Unhandled Runtime Error
>
> Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was
> rendered on the server.
>
> Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching < h2 > in < section >.
>
> See more info here:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error Component Stack
> Call Stack throwOnHydrationMismatch
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (12507:0)
> tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (12535:0)
> updateHostComponent
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (19902:0)
> beginWork node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js
> (21618:0) callCallback
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (4164:0)
> invokeGuardedCallbackDev
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (4213:0)
> invokeGuardedCallback
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (4277:0)
> beginWork$1 node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js
> (27451:0) performUnitOfWork
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26557:0)
> workLoopSync node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js
> (26466:0) renderRootSync
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26434:0)
> performConcurrentWorkOnRoot
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25738:0) workLoop
> node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (266:0) flushWork
> node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (239:0)
> performWorkUntilDeadline
> node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (533:0)

When I close the error window, the page looks like it should, however I am still getting the error on the next render.

While the error mentions tags h2 and section, I didn't notice anything wrong about them. By trial and error, I have been commenting out different parts of the index page to see which part caused the error. Finally, removing the following video tag stopped the error from occurring:

```
  <video
    autoPlay
    preload="auto"
    loop
    muted
    className={styles.video}
  >
    <source src="/landing/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
  </video>
```

Why is this simple video causing the error? How can I keep this video on my landing page and maintain SSR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out it was an issue of browser extension "Video Speed Controler", which is changing the source code in browser, but not in the server. After disabling the extension, no more warning.